# Is there an exchange in RabbitMQ that allows using AND, OR or other logical operators in routing keys?

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to build a filter for job-postings along different criteria.

For instance a job posting could be classified along Location, Technology Stack and Nature of Engagement. I want to set the routing key for each job posting according to the aforementioned attributes. However I am running into the problem where I feel like I need logical operators within the routing keys,

For example the routing key for a job posting could be

NewYork.(Java AND JavaScript AND Elixir).(Full time OR Intern)

I see this increasing to other attributes (Visa sponsorship, Salary, Benefits etc) and each attribute having multiple states joined by AND, OR etc (Eg. the technology stack can have a number of languages and tools)

This is on the producer side. Likewise on the consumer side I'd like to have queues where I can provide binding keys using Logical operators and receive messages.

I have looked at Fanout, Direct, Topic and Header Exchanges but I'm not able to figure out how to go about this problem using one of these exchanges.

Is there a custom exchange that provides the kind of functionality I require or is there an efficient way to break this problem and use a Topic exchange to achieve what I want instead of using logical operators?

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why do you need a consumer for a specific combination of those properties?

Comment: @AlexBuyny Assuming someone subscribes for a list of job postings with those attributes, I'd be able to filter out the relevant job postings as per their preferences and send those across

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a rabbit consumer for each user who subscribes? Instead I would just store user preferences in a data store and when job comes in, will get the list of users by matching their preferences against the post attributes, and then send emails to them.